# Are ANTLR parsers for Java thread safe?

Tags: thread-safety, antlr

Is an ANTLR (v3.2) generated Java parser thread safe?

For example, in a servlet request handler, can I reuse the same parser instance to parse a request body? The requests may come in on different threads, so parsing must be done in a thread safe manner. if instances are thread safe, I can reuse the same instance in each request; else I must pool them or create new instances. The [ANTLRv3 FAQ](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/ANTLR+v3+FAQ) is silent on thread safety.

There is an ancient (2000) [jGuru question](http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=93725) about this, and the answer there,

> Typically this question is really asking, "can I make multiple
>   instances of the same parser and parse multiple input streams at the
>   same time?"

makes the wrong assumption.

Since it is not mentioned in the ANTLR FAQ, I assume parsers are **not** thread safe.

Answer (score 6):

In ANTLR 3, there are no guarantees regarding thread safety. In ANTLR 4, instance methods are not safe for multi-threaded operations, but you may create two separate instances of the parser and use those separate instances on multiple threads.